# Cloudfront backed S3 bucket: listing bucket contents over https with prefix

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, directory-listing

I have a Cloudfront distribution that is backed by an S3 bucket. I'm trying to list the contents of a subdirectory (prefix) within the bucket, but I'm getting a list of the entire bucket contents rather than just the objects with a given prefix.

It's important to note that I have to do this by making a direct https request to the Cloudfront domain directly (not by using the AWS cli or the AWS S3 APIs).

I am able to successfully download/upload objects from the Cloudfront domain using signed cookies to authenticate. And I can clearly list all the objects on the bucket (the auth works), but I'm not able to return only objects with a given prefix.

I also have a bucket policy that allows the following on the bucket itself:

- `s3:ListBucket`
- `s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads`

And the following on the bucket objects:

`s3:GetObject`, `s3:GetObjectAttributes`, `s3:GetObjectVersion`, `s3:GetObjectTagging`,  `s3:GetObjectVersionTagging`, `s3:PutObject`, `s3:PutObjectVersionTagging`, `s3:PutObjectTagging`, `s3:DeleteObject`, `s3:DeleteObjectTagging`, `s3:DeleteObjectVersionTagging`, `s3:AbortMultipartUpload`,  `s3:ListMultipartUploadParts`

When I try this query, the response returns the entire contents of the directory:

```
import requests
cookies = {...} # cookies needed to authenticate with cloudfront; this is working correctly
res = requests.get("https://example.cloudfront.net/?prefix=myprefix/", cookies=cookies)
```

... it gives me a big xml document.

```
<ListBucketResult xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
  <Name>mybucket</Name>
  <Prefix/>
  <Marker/>
  <MaxKeys>1000</MaxKeys>
  <IsTruncated>true</IsTruncated>
  <Contents>
    <Key>some-other-prefix-I-do-not-want/myfile.text</Key>
    ...
  </Contents>
  <Contents>
  ...
</ListBucketResult>
```

Or if I try this query, the params have no effect and I get the entire bucket contents (I think this is using the S3 api, so maybe that's why this particular query doesn't work)

```
params = {"list-type": "2", "delimiter": "/", "prefix": "myprefix"}
res = requests.get("https://example.cloudfront.net", cookies=cookies, params=params)
```

When I try this query, I get a 404.

```
res = requests.get("https://example.cloudfront.net/myprefix/", cookies=cookies)
```

Does anyone know how I can list only the objects with a given prefix when listing the files from a Cloudfront distribution?

Comment: Is your cache policy configured to pass along query strings?

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. That was the problem; it was blocking the query parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer to this and am posting it for anyone who encounters it. I needed to add a custom `Origin Request` Policy on my Cloudfront distribution. The policy is a copy of the AWS-provided `CORS-S3Origin` policy, with the additional query strings added to allow those query parameters to pass through Cloudfront to the S3 API.

So, for example, under `Cloudfront > Policies > Origin request > Create origin request policy`, I created a policy with all of the headers from the `CORS-S3Origin` policy plus I added Query strings for `list-type`, `max-keys`, `delimiter`, `prefix`, and `start-after`. Basically, I added any parameters that I wanted to pass though Cloudfront to S3 as documented on AWS's S3 API Reference [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_ListObjectsV2.html)

[image]

Then, I just needed to attach that policy to my Cloudfront distribution by going to `Cloudfront > Distributions > My Distribution` and Edit my distribution. Then, I select the "Behaviors" tab on my distribution, edit that behavior, and change the Origin request policy to my custom policy that I just created.

[image]

Once I made that change, I was able to filter the response as follows:

```py
import requests
res = requests.get("https://example.cloudfront.net/?prefix=path/inside/my/bucket", cookies=cookies)

from lxml import objectify
root = objectify.fromstring(res.text.encode())
for contents in root.Contents:
    print(contents.Key)
```